# Service account in one project inherit permissions of service account in other project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

If Project A has SA x and Project B has SA y is it possible to have y inherit from x? Ie any new permissions that x gains, y would gain too.

(Ideally this inheritance could be specific to eg only Bigquery permissions, but that is not necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the manner you described: `y inherit from x`.

Google does support delegation chains so that `y` can impersonate `x`, but then the resulting permissions are `x`'s, not the union of `x` and `y`.

An IAM member (user and service account) can be part of a group, which might achieve your goal. Grant a permission (IAM role) to the group and the members inherit the additional permissions.